# Auth:: Doesnt Recognize User Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

Ive been working on my login ..
im stuck on auth::user()->*column* this suppose to show the ID but it says that

Trying to get property of non-object

```
<< ? php
namespace App\ Http\ Controllers;
use Illuminate\ Http\ Request;
use App\ Users;
use App\ Login;
use Illuminate\ Support\ Facades\ DB;
use Illuminate\ Support\ Facades\ Auth;
use DateTime;
use DateInterval;
class HomeController extends Controller {
//
    public function index() {
        $id = Auth::user() - > User_ID;
        dd( $id );
        return view( 'Home' ) - > with( compact( "id" ) );
    }
}
```

could you find the problem?

Thankyou in advance!
and thankyou for your attention

Comment: You can not add space in `Auth::user()->User_ID` . Just remove spaces and you are done

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is just a typo and can't be reproduced.

Comment: Your primary column should be `id` not `User_ID`

Comment: Yoshua Novaldy, what happened? have you tried anything?

Comment: the problem wasnt the space..

Comment: on logincontroller if i do Auth::check,, the user was authenticated,,
on logincontroller i give 

Auth::login($user[0]); 
return redirect('Home');
Route::get('/Home','HomeController@index');

on homecontroller i check Auth::check, the user  wasnt authenticated

Comment: Also look at `Auth::id()`

Comment: null.. is that a problem?

Comment: You can check authenticated user details using `dd(Auth::user())` . Please do that and check yourself or post the output here.

Comment: Auth::login($user[0]);
dd(Auth::user());

the user was authenticated,, with all the data on database..

but when i do
dd(Auth::user()) on Homecontroller, the output is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use default users table. And remove space after user(). It should be.

```
public function index() {
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    dd( $id );
    return view('Home')->with( compact( "id" ) );
}
```

In your case

```
$id = Auth::user()->User_Id;
```

Comment: on logincontroller if i do Auth::check,, the user was authenticated,, on logincontroller i give Auth::login($user[0]); return redirect('Home'); Route::get('/Home','HomeController@index'); on homecontroller i check Auth::check, the user wasnt authenticated
thankyou for helping me!

Comment: In HomeController user does not authenticated. When a user login then In LoginController user will be authenticated through his credential. And in HomeController you can check that user is already login or not using Auth::check();

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not getting the user authenticated, but still you are trying to get column value of the user. So first, please check if user is logged in or not.

```
public function index() {
    if (Auth::check()) {    // Checking if user is logged in.
        // The user is logged in...
        $id = Auth::user()->User_ID;
        dd( $id );
        return view('Home')->with( compact( "id" ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: the user wasn authenticated.. i dont know why

Comment: on logincontroller if i do Auth::check,, the user was authenticated,,
on logincontroller i give Auth::login($user[0]); return redirect('Home');
on homecontroller i did the same as you say, the user  wasnt authenticated

thankyou for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

check if your routes are in proper middleware they may not start session so you cant get authenticate